# jQuery Chosen Not Work If Add Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I am adding new row dynamically through javascript, having jQuery chosen dropdown and textboxes. The textboxes are fine, however, the newly added dropdown in a row is not working (even not clickable). If I use simple html dropdown then it will work fine. 
Please help...

**HTML**

```html
<table id="POITable" border="1" width="100%">
<select data-placeholder="Select Product" id="productsList" class="chosen-select" style="width:200px;" tabindex="2" onchange="getProductName();">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Test1">Test 1</option>
            <option value="Test2">Test 2</option>
            </select>
                </td>
           <td><input size=25 type="text" id="latbox"/></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="lngbox" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="delPOIbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="addmorePOIbutton" value="Add" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

**Javascript**

```js
function insRow()
{
    var x=document.getElementById('POITable');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp3.id += len;
    inp3.value = '';

    x.appendChild( new_row );
}
```

Comment: concept is simple, apply plugin after you create dynamic html

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352207/jquery-chosen-plugin-add-options-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

have you tried firing the "chosen:updated" event:

```
$('#productsList').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

after adding the new options to the select?

**Later edit:** if you're using an older version of chosen, the event might be called "liszt:updated"

Comment: Actually, I am not adding new options, I am duplicating whole control with method insRow()

Comment: after x.appendChild(new_row) insert:
$(new_row.getElementsByTagName("select")[0]).chosen();

Answer (score 0):

Its a CSS issue, just add this code snippet in your script

```
$(".chosen-container").css("min-width","220px");
```