# custom values for chosen-Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Is it possible to enter custom values for the (select) `Chosen` Plugin, to create a own value as option?

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: If you mean that you want to create a new `option` element in the chosen plugin, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352207/jquery-chosen-plugin-add-options-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible just call this function onClick and pass custom values in the parameter

```
        function customTags(tagName)
            {
               var customTagLength = $('li.search-choice').length;   //Custom Option length -1 as compare to actual Option length
               if(customTagLength>9)
               {
                   return false;
               }
             // above code to limit select value in chosen  


            var html = '<option value="'+tagName+'">'+tagName+'</option>';
            $('.chosen-select').append(html);

    //This is what you need        
            var SearchChoiceArrayTagName = [tagName];
            $('.chosen-select').find('option').filter(function (idx, option) {
            if($.inArray(option.value, SearchChoiceArrayTagName) !== -1) {
                return option;
            }
            }).prop('selected', 'true');

            $('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");


                    $('.chosen-select').chosen().change(function(e, params){
                                if(params.deselected==tagName)
                            {
                                $(".chosen-select option[value='"+tagName+"']").remove();
                                $(".chosen-select").trigger('chosen:updated');

                            }
                    }); 
            }
```