# Making select box searchable html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am dynamically adding `select` elements in the webpage when a certain action is taken by the user. The problem is that as the select elements are added dynamically, the `jquery` is unable to make them searchable as it is applied when the document is loaded. How can I make the dynamically added select boxes searchable?

**EDIT**

I'm using [select bootstrap](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for making the select element searchable.

What I am doing is making the user select multiple parts of an image using [select areas](https://github.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas) and whenever an area is selected, I add a select element corresponding to that area. This is done using a custom javascript in the head of the page. However, these select elements are devoid of any styling as the are added dynamically.

The select bootstrap can make a select element searchable by using `data-live-search` -

```
<select data-live-search="true" name="category_name" class="selectpicker" >
```

Comment: What do you mean searchable? You mean found by selectors? Ideally, pPost some code.

Comment: What jQuery code? Are we supposed to guess? I can however guess you need a *delegated event handler* to cover this situation :)

Comment: How does your current search work?

Comment: You haveN'T shared your codebase. We don't know, what issue you are facing. If you are looking for a library, then try Select2 plugin
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: I have edited the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). It is very easy to use, just include the files and call it like this:

```
$(".my-select").chosen();
```

And if you want to add options dynamically, you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19545998/2127296), which explains how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the elements with a selector, even if you bind them dynamically:

```js
$('option').each(function(){console.log($(this).html())});

$('select').append('<option class="option2">test 2</option>');

$('option').each(function(){console.log($(this).html())});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option class="option1">test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't seem to work. I have edited the question, please have a look.